# Removing attributes of an element when another node is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background**: I am working with an eforms platform that contains an uploader that generates base64 and stores it in the DOM. The uploader doesn't allow easy viewing of uploaded images, so I'm working on something that iterates through data-uris in the upload field and populates these to an image gallery below.

```
<!-- this block is stripped down version of the DOM created by the uploader -->
<div class="upload_field">
    <div>
        <li data-name="animal.jpg">
            <button data-name="animal.jpg" data-uri="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..">animal.jpg</button>
        </li>
        <li data-name="gonzo.jpg">
            <button data-name="gonzo.jpg" data-uri="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ...">gonzo.jpg</button>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- gallery code from here -->
<script>
  setInterval(function () {
    $.each($('.upload_field').find('li'), function (index) {
      const uploadBase64 = $(this).find('button').attr('data-uri');
      const uploadName = $(this).find('button').attr('data-name');
      if (uploadBase64) {
        $('#image_holder' + index).attr({src:uploadBase64, alt:uploadName});
      }
      else {
        $('#image_holder' + index).removeAttr('src alt');
      }
    })
  }, 1000);
</script>

<img id="image_holder0">
<img id="image_holder1">
<img id="image_holder2">
<img id="image_holder3">
<img id="image_holder4">
etc...
```

**Issue**: Using `$.each`, this handles any number of uploads to initially populate the gallery. However, when an upload is deleted, the node is removed from the DOM so the `$.each` no longer iterates over it, meaning the else statement in the code is never hit and the `<img>` tags it initially populated aren't cleared (the image gets stuck as whatever used to be there).

How do I clear linked `<img>` attributes for files that are removed after uploading, so the gallery only contains images that still exist?

Comment: Using incremental ID's gets overly complicated fast when you need to add/remove elements. Why would you need to run this loop every second in the first place? When you delete an `<li>` should also delete the `<img>` element then use indexing to match them

Comment: And if you bind your image-creation/deletion function to an event, or custom event, fired by the `<li>` elements when a new image is uploaded/added or removed then it's probably easier to keep track of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess removing the img elements entirely is the better option then. The interval was just while I was testing, I was going to tackle binding it to an event once the rest of it was working properly. A bit off-topic, but what would be the correct way of triggering the function when a <li> node was inserted?

Comment: There isn't an easy way to detect if an element has been added without polling. I don't really see the need for it too. Does the provider use an callback for when a new image is uploaded?

Comment: If you remove an `<li>` you can [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to remove corresponding image. When you add an `<li>` presumably it gets appended to end of list and an `<img>` can be inserted simutaneously

Comment: Why not simply use a `MutationObserver`?